# changing pattern by removing spaces?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, awk, regular-expression

file :

```
hi hello,new york,      ,  ,brazil site   ,brazil
january,month is feb   ,      , ,indiana jones
```

task:

- delete all horizontal space (spaces and tab) between any two comas (like ,     ,) if there is no character other than space.
  so it would look like :

  ```
  hi hello,new york,,,brazil site   ,brazil
  january,month is feb   ,,,indiana jones
  ```
- also, delete any trailing or leading horizontal space (space and tab) for each parameter
  so that it looks like this.

  final output:

  ```
  hi hello,new york,,,brazil site,brazil
  january,month is feb,,,indiana jones
  ```

NOTE: The parameters itself has spaces like `hi hello` and `indiana jones` etc. It should not be affected and become like `hihello` or `indianajones`. If possible a solution with awk, otherwise sed will also do.

I am unable to achive the first task with sed like this:

```
sed -n 's/,[[:blank:]],/,,/gp' file
```

but i get this as output:

```
january,month is feb   ,      ,,indiana jones
```

Comment: Probably I misunderstand you, but why not just `sed 's/ *, */,/g' file`?

Comment: thanks @manatwork it works, u got this this was easy and i have been thinking a lot.

Comment: @manatwork, better `sed 's/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,/g` to catch tabs too.

Comment: Right. Or `sed 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file` to type less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possibilities with sed:

1. Simplest one (matching a space character zero or more times before a comma, and a space character zero or more times after the comma, replacing it by just a comma—and this many times, thus using the option `g` for *global*):

   ```
   sed 's/ *, */,/g' file
   ```

   **Time for this command:** 3.056s, with `perl -p -e` instead of `sed` 5.932s
2. `[:space:]` means all whitespace characters, thus being the same as `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`. [This is POSIX standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes):

   ```
   sed 's/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,/g' file
   ```

   **Time for this command:** 10.365s, with `perl -p -e` instead of `sed` 9.060s
3. And finally the abbreviated version with `\s`, which stands for the same as `[:space:]` but is [Perl syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes):

   ```
   sed 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
   ```

   **Time for this command:** 10.507s, with `perl -p -e` instead of `sed` 6.126s

All of them result in

```
hi hello,new york,,,brazil site,brazil
january,month is feb,,,indiana jones
```

---

The **time** was taken for a file with 2M lines (containing the questions example text 1M times). The file was 97MBytes big.

The first command seems to be the fastest with `sed`. The last command is the fastest when using perl and taking into account, that it replaces not only spaces but also tabstops, linefeed and so on.

Comment: All 3 regular expressions work in `perl`'s replacement mode too =) `perl -pi -e 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file`

Comment: To have the same as `sed` you should have written `perl -p -e` to be non in place editing. Your example `perl -pi -e` is the same as `sed -i`.

Comment: ah yes. was thinking file replacement from the question.

Answer (score 4):

So, you are asking awk:

```
awk '{$1=$1};gsub(" ,",",")'
```

Will this do?
Note that this have the side-effect of removing duplicated space in your data inside commas, which might not be a problem for English.

Comment: May you please explain the command? What is this `$1=$1` for?

Comment: '$1=$1' is a refreshing, that tells awk to *refresh* the data it reads from input, after that $0 is changed, and output is re-structured with OFS(the out put seperater)

Comment: **Time for this command:** 5.038s and for the easier to understand and less to write version `awk 'gsub(" +,",",")'` only 3.061s. Same time as for the simple `sed` command in my answer.